# How to remove Unwanted line between Gradients?

Tags: ios, uitableview, gradient

In my application I am using custom backgroungView for all UItableViewCell
Below is the code for drawing gradient in my UIview subclass
In this class I get color from the client class in array with `[sectionGradient objectAtIndex:0]` being the center color and `[sectionGradient objectAtIndex:0]`  being the edge color

```
/// in Bacckground.m file
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        //// Color Declarations

        CGColorRef centerColor = [[self.sectionGradient objectAtIndex:0] CGColor];
        CGColorRef edgeColor =[[self.sectionGradient objectAtIndex:1] CGColor];

        //// Gradient Declarations
        CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[(__bridge id)centerColor, (__bridge id)edgeColor], gradientLocations);
        CGFloat gradient2Locations[] = {0, 1};
        CGGradientRef gradient2 = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[(__bridge id)edgeColor, (__bridge id)centerColor], gradient2Locations);

        //// Rectangle Drawing
        UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0,rect.size.width,rect.size.height/2)];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        [rectanglePath addClip];
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient2, CGPointMake(0,0), CGPointMake(0,rect.size.height/2), 0);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);


        //// Rectangle 2 Drawing
        UIBezierPath* rectangle2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0,rect.size.height/2,rect.size.width,rect.size.height/2)];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        [rectangle2Path addClip];
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,rect.size.height/2), CGPointMake(0,rect.size.height), 0);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);


        //// Cleanup
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient2);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

But if I assign the above class as `backgroundView` for cell I get the below result

[image]

As you can see there is an unnecessary line in the middle of the cell. I don't know how it comes.

Help me to spot the line which render the line

FYI:- If I set the separator property for tableView as none then I get like below

[image]

Comment: Why not use a single gradient with three components instead?
It *might* be a rounding problem - try casting to int: (int) (rect.size.height/2)

Comment: @Eiko both of your solutions work like charm. I can understand how the first one help, but I can't figure out how rounding off would help , In my application the tableView height is 60 so in both types(int,float) the value will be 30. Can you explain it as an answer

Comment: Is the rect (try a breakpoint in your code) also exactly 60? Not sure if the separator is included or not... Your experiment suggests that it has influence on the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by using three gradient Location and three colors as adviced by Eiko

I changed the gradient drawing like below

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
        //// Color Declarations

        CGColorRef centerColor = [[self.sectionGradient objectAtIndex:0] CGColor];
        CGColorRef edgeColor =[[self.sectionGradient objectAtIndex:1] CGColor];

        //// Gradient Declarations
        CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0,0.5,1};
        CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[(__bridge id)edgeColor,(__bridge id)centerColor, (__bridge id)edgeColor], gradientLocations);


        //// Rectangle Drawing
        UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0,rect.size.width,rect.size.height)];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        [rectanglePath addClip];
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,0), CGPointMake(0,rect.size.height), 0);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CGGradientRelease(gradient);

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

And below is the result

[image]

U can also solve this by casting the float value to int as said in the comment by Eiko

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this:

```
[rectangle2Path addClip];
```

Comment: still find the black line

Comment: Try to remove [rectangle2Path addClip];